# How do you insert a background image on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

How do you insert a background image on Google Docs? It seems that this feature wasn't supported before?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Self-answered questions should follow the same guidelines as regular questions... they should show what was tried, include a brief description of the search efforts... ref. [ask].

Comment: Related to posting questions to be self-answered [Is there an etiquette for asking questions originally intended to be self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349140/289691)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now insert background images on Google Docs as follows:

1. Open the header section of the document
2. Paste the desired background image
3. Right-click on the image and select `image options`
4. Under text wrapping, select `Behind text`
5. Under `Position`, set to `Fix position on page` and then `x=0` and `y=0`
6. Adjust the header height using the ruler on the left so that the image can start at the top
7. Resize the image to take the full dimensions of the page